# bad class file magic (cafebabe) error when adding mysql-connector.jar to build path

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a database using JDBC, which requires mysql-connector.jar, but whenever I try to build the project, I get the error:

`Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`

I checked upon the cafebabe error, and I found that other people are getting the same error when including other dependencies, but I might've somehow missed the solution to mysql-connector. I would really appreciate your help in this.
The mysql-connector version is 5.1.38, and I tried building the project using different apis.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information about this error. Looks like a problem with JDK version or with `mysql-connector.jar`. You should use JDK 1.6 to compile your project and have `mysql-connector.jar` compiled with the same (or less) version.

You can use JDK 1.7 with Android too, but I am not sure that everything will work correctly.

And using an Android device to connect directly to the database is a bad practice.

Comment: I'm now writing a socket server which will communicate with a python server, and then that will connect to the database, to check the login information, I think it's better this way.

Comment: @FeRi Yes. You are right. It is better to use `JSON` or `XML` by HTTP (REST, SOAP) to communicate to the server.